# Add List of Data to a class and then call that same list of data in a different class

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am caching a list of data that I pull from my db and all I am trying to do is is pull the data from that same cache search it and then display it.

```
CachedList.Add("SearchableItems", Items, null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, onRemove);
```

I am using System.Web.Caching;

then I have another class to grab that list of SearchableItems but everywhere I look it says oh just use

```
Cache["SearchableItems"]
```

but when I do that it just say class cannot be inherited. Could someone please just post a super basic example of putting a list in a cache then retrieving it. Also could you please give some code context cause the little I have found has none

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

Adding :

```
var list = new List<string>();
...
if (Cache["Key1"] == null)
 { 
      Cache.Insert("Key1", list, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
 }
```

Selecting :

```
var list = Cache["Key1"] as List<string>;
```